# Apache Camel: Does MockEndpoint with 'mock:direct:foo' URI correctly mock an endpoint with 'direct:foo' URI?

Tags: apache-camel, integration

Does MockEndpoint with 'mock:direct:foo' URI correctly mock an endpoint with 'direct:foo' URI? 
Does this even make any sense ?

Comment: Ok, I read the reference, and if you add this method to your test: `public String isMockEndpoints() { return "*"; }` then - yes, `mock:direct:foo` does mock the endpoint `direct:foo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the Cookbook in Camel Manual, this is what I understand.

mock:direct:foo acts as mock for direct:foo but not in the same sense as we Mock some regular java objects.

Illustrating:
There is a route that sends a message to endpoint with uri as direct:foo
Once we write

```
 public String isMockEndpoints() { return "*"; }
```

in our test class. We are asking to mock all endpoints that are associated with the routes in the context of the test class. In our case, the only end point we have is direct:foo. So what the above peice of code does is to create a new endpoint

```
 mock:direct:foo
```

This endpoint is 'said to be' mocking direct:foo

What happens now, when a message is send destined for direct:foo.
It first is sent to end point

```
 mock:direct:foo
```

Here testing in terms of assertions we define are executed.
Afterwards, the message is sent to the original end point

```
direct:foo
```